# Difficulty running python from command line

Tags: python

I am new to the Raspberry Pi and Linux. I have seen many tutorials and cannot figure out to run .py files from command line. All i get are error messages about wrong directories and files not found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to run a Python script on your Pi by navigating to the directory where your Python file is located, and then typing `python scriptname.py`.Just type `python` before your python filename and then it should run the script.